# Joy-IT RS232 Shield and RS232 voltage levels

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, shields, voltage-level, rs232

First of all, sorry if this is a dumb question, but I'm pretty new to the whole Serial RS232 concepts.

I do have an Arduino Board that, from what I read about, is not able to communicate via RS232 because of different levels.

My question now is: If the [Joy-IT RS232 Shield](https://joy-it.net/en/products/ARD-RS232) will make up for that. So is this shield handling the RS232 level shift? I don't really know what to look for so I am asking here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that shield will handle the level shifting for you. If you look closely at the images of the shield, you see the MAX232 chip, which is a commonly used chip for getting UART (which is the Serial interface of the Arduino) to speak over RS232.

And yes, RS232 uses different voltage levels. The UART on a microcontroller usually uses the voltages 0V and 5V (or 3.3V depending on  it's supply voltage), which is also called TTL levels (Transistor-Transistor Logic), while RS232 mostly works with +-10V (though different voltages are also inside the standard). You see, that this is a symmetrical voltage around ground (0V).

Comment: Wow thanks for the detailed answer! Then this shield is exactly what I need for my project.